# Wordpress c-panel login error

Tags: login

I have installed WordPress with a quick install but can not access the C-panel. When I try to follow the link given in credentials I get this error - 404: Page not found. Please advise me how to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: First of all, are you sure you used www.domain.com/wp-admin or www.domain.com/admin? (Or without the www)

Answer (score 0):

If you just buy the domain name then it takes some hours for the nameservers to be updated, you will have to wait or if you know the ip of your site you can write for now on your hosts file of your computer

Ip. Address  www.sitename.gr

And your site will be reachable

If you see the domain name then the quick install failed, try installing with other quick install apps or manually